# How to set the maximum width of a column in CSS Grid Layout?

Tags: html, css, units-of-measurement, css-grid

**What I want to achieve:**

Using [CSS Grid Layout](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Grid_Layout), to have a page with a right column which size is derived from its content, but only up to 20% of the window width.

**How I thought it would work:**

```css
div {
  border-style: solid;
}

#container {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr minmax(auto, 20%);
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div>
    some content
  </div>
  <div>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec cursus eu leo ac ultrices. Vivamus ornare, orci sed pretium sollicitudin
  </div>
</div>
```

It looks good, but then when I remove the content of the second `div`, the left column does not collapse:

```css
div {
  border-style: solid;
}

#container {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr minmax(auto, 20%);
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div>
    some content
  </div>
  <div></div>
</div>
```

**My question:**

I was under the impression that since [`minmax()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/minmax)

> (...) defines a size range greater than or equal to min and less than
>   or equal to max.

it would mean that in my case the width is set from `auto` (= `0` when the `div` is empty) to `20%`. It however stays at 20%. Why is it so?

Comment: *I would like to have a page with a right column* there are many other ways to achieve this, Is there any specific reason for using `grid-template-columns`?

Comment: @AbhishekPandey: yes, the whole app is based on CSS Grid (I will clarify that in the question)

Answer (score 68, accepted):

"The fit-content function accepts one param, the maximum value. A grid column/row with this property set will still take up as little space as necessary, according to its content, but no more than the maximum value."

See this article: [Becoming a CSS Grid Ninja!](https://medium.com/@elad/becoming-a-css-grid-ninja-f4c6db018cc1)

You can solve your case while still making use of percentage-based maximums:

```css
div {
  outline: 1px dotted gray;
}

.container {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr fit-content(20%);
}

.container div {
  overflow: hidden; /* this needs to be set so that width respects fit-content */
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div>
    some content
  </div>
  <div>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec cursus eu leo ac ultrices. Vivamus ornare, orci sed pretium sollicitudin
  </div>
</div>

<div class="container">
  <div>
    some content
  </div>
  <div></div>
</div>
```

Comment: this will cause that column to shrink to fit the content in it

Comment: When this answer was posted, `fit-content()` had more limited browser support. Today, it still requires a prefix in Firefox. https://caniuse.com/#search=fit-content

Comment: Adding `overflow: hidden;` to the direct children of the grid which are the columns themselves was the trick for me.

Answer (score 29):

You've misunderstood `minmax` function. It first tries to apply maximum value and when that's not possible, it applies minimum.

So to fix your layout, you just need to calculate `20%` of your container width, apply it using `max-width` property for you grid item, and use `auto` in your `grid-template-columns` property definition for the second column. Demo:

```css
div {
  outline: 1px dotted gray;
}

.container {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr auto;
}

.container > :nth-child(2) {
  max-width: 60px; /* 20% x 300px */
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div>
    some content
  </div>
  <div>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec cursus eu leo ac ultrices. Vivamus ornare, orci sed pretium sollicitudin
  </div>
</div>

<div class="container">
  <div>
    some content
  </div>
  <div></div>
</div>
```

---

Update: More flexible solution will be to use `fit-content` function from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57313344/1548895).

Comment: Ah. I read *defines a size range greater than or equal to min and less than or equal to max* as a continuum from min to max. Your explanation is way more precise. Thank you. In that case `max-width` will indeed be the way to go (I was hoping to avoid two entries for the same dimension-setting action on the column)

Answer (score 15):

You might need to set the `max-width` on the container itself and let its column set to `auto`.

```css
div,
aside {
  border-style: solid;
}

#container {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr auto;
}

aside {
  max-width: 60px; /* 60px is 20% of 300px*/
  /* max-width:20%; 20% of window's */
  font-size: 0;
  transition: 0.25s;
}

#container:hover aside {
  font-size: 1em;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div>
    Hover it to see aside grow till 20% average width
  </div>
  <aside>lets give a try to resize it from content</aside>
</div>
```

Answer (score 11):

Use clamp()

```
grid-template-columns: clamp(350px, 40%, 500px) auto;
```

Wheree clamp take three parameters (min, preferred, max)