# minmax() in Grid not working as expected - always using max value

Tags: tailwind-css, css-grid

Consider the following code:

```
<div className="grid grid-cols-[minmax(100px,300px)_auto] grid-rows-1">
<div className="bg-red-600">
  left leftleft left left left left left left left left left left left
  left left left left left left left left left left left left left left
  left left left left left left left left left left left left
</div>
<div>main content</div>
</div>
```

That works fine, the maximum width of the first column is 300px:
[image]

However, when reducing the content for the left div, it does not shrink in width (it only looks a little bit shorter due to not perfect screenshot)

```
<div className="grid grid-cols-[minmax(100px,300px)_auto] grid-rows-1">
 <div className="bg-red-600">left</div>   <--- shorter content now
 <div className="bg-yellow-600">main content</div>
</div>
```

[image]

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider using [`fit-content()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/fit-content_function) to *clamp* the grid column track to `300px`. If you'd still like the `100px` minimum column track size as implied by the first `100px` argument in your original post, consider applying `min-width: 100px` via `min-w-[100px]` to the first element.

```html
<script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com/3.3.2"></script>

<div class="grid grid-cols-[fit-content(300px)_auto] grid-rows-1">
  <div class="bg-red-600">
    left leftleft left left left left left left left left left left left
    left left left left left left left left left left left left left left
    left left left left left left left left left left left left
  </div>
  <div>main content</div>
</div>

<div class="grid grid-cols-[fit-content(300px)_auto] grid-rows-1">
  <div class="bg-red-600">left</div>   <!--- shorter content now -->
  <div class="bg-yellow-600">main content</div>
</div>

<div class="grid grid-cols-[fit-content(300px)_auto] grid-rows-1">
  <div class="bg-red-600 min-w-[100px]">left</div>
  <div class="bg-yellow-600">main content</div>
</div>
```

Comment: perfect, thank you! For other readers, I've misunderstood the minmax function: `It first tries to apply maximum value and when that's not possible, it applies minimum.` (from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45459151/how-to-set-the-maximum-width-of-a-column-in-css-grid-layout)